# Ruby refinements gotchas

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, refinements

In [Metaprogramming Ruby 2](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2) in Chapter 2 at the "**Refinements**" section I found the following piece of Ruby code:

```
class MyClass 
  def my_method
    "original my_method()"
  end

  def another_method 
    my_method
  end

end

module MyClassRefinement 
  refine MyClass do
    def my_method
      "refined my_method()"
    end 
  end
end

using MyClassRefinement
MyClass.new.my_method # => "refined my_method()"
MyClass.new.another_method # => "original my_method()" - How is this possible?
```

According to the author:

> However, the call to `another_method`
>   could catch you off guard: even if you call `another_method` after `using`, the call to `my_method` itself happens before `using` — so it calls the original, unrefined version of the method.

This totally trips me up.

Why `MyClass.new.another_method` prints "original my_method()" since its used after `using MyClassRefinement` and what is the author trying to say here?

Could anyone provide a more intuitive/better explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably because the remapping introduced by refinements only applies to a particular scope, and within that original definition the scope is unaffected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best explanation I can find is from [the docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Scope):

> Refinements are lexical in scope. Refinements are only active within a scope after the call to `using`. Any code before the `using` statement will not have the refinement activated.

That means your refinement method must be invoked somewhere after the call to `using`. The actual location of the method's invocation is what matters, not how the method was invoked or from where the method was invoked.

---

Here's what happens.

1. `using` i.e. `using MyClassRefinement` activates the `my_method` refinement.
2. `MyClass.new.my_method` is executed.
3. A [method lookup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) ensues from the exact point of invocation:

> When looking up a method for an instance of `class C` Ruby checks:
>
> - If refinements are active for `C`, in the reverse order they were activated
>
>   - The prepended modules from the refinement for `C`
>   - The refinement for `C`
>   - The included modules from the refinement for `C`
> - The prepended modules of `C`
> - `C`
> - The included modules of `C`

4. Refinements *are active*, and `my_method` returns the code from the refinement `"refined my_method()"`
5. `MyClass.new.another_method` is executed.
6. The [method lookup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) ensues from the exact point of invocation.
7. Refinements *are active* at this point of invocation, but the `another_method` is not a refinement, so Ruby looks for `another_method` in the class `MyClass` and finds it.
8. Inside of the class method `another_method`, the method `my_method` is found and invoked.
9. The [method lookup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) ensues from the exact point of invocation.
10. At the point of invocation there are no refinements active, because there have been no calls to `using` **above the line** (i.e. physically prior to) where `my_method` is invoked. Ruby goes on to look for `my_method` in the class `MyClass` and finds it.
11. `my_method` returns the code from the class method `"original my_method()"`.

    ---

We can make a simple comparison. Let's say I have one isolated `file.rb` with the following code:

```
puts puppy
puppy = 'waggle'
```

`puppy` can't be used before it is defined. The variable is lexically scoped, and its use depends on the location of its definition in the isolated `file.rb`.

Similarly, a **refinement** cannot be invoked until it has been activated via `using` on a previous line (or somewhere physically previous within the source code file). The refinement is [lexically scoped](http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-ruby-refinements-and-lexical-scope/).

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope)

> In languages with **lexical scope** (also called **static scope**), name resolution depends on the location in the source code and the **lexical context**, which is defined by where the named variable or function is defined...
>
> Lexical resolution can be determined at compile time, and is also known as **early binding**, while dynamic resolution can in general only be determined at run time, and thus is known as **late binding**.

---

Your specific issue with refinements is discussed in the last section of **[this article](https://blog.alex-miller.co/ruby/2017/07/22/scope-the-monkey.html)**. The author explains as well how the `using` statement's physical location in the file determines whether or not a refinement is active.

Comment: Thank you! It makes total sense now! Lexical scoping was the true culprit.

Comment: ...and your references helped a lot!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped

Comment: @kstratis: Just remember that the *whole point* of refinements is that they provide monkey patching *without affecting other code*. That's precisely what you are seeing here. You are monkey patching `my_method` without affecting `another_method`.